# Unable to create new android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android and I installed Android Studio in my 2 PC. The other one is in office and the the other is on my own personal laptop. In PC version when creating a new Android Studio Project there will be a portion that you can select what template to use. And after the creation of template there will be some sort of phone image in the middle and there are some widgets in the right side which you can drag and drop. So I have no issue there. But in my PC. When I create new project 
`File > New > Project` 
There's no template selection and when I proceed there's only a blank space and in my navigator I have this folder structure:

```
untitled3
 - .idea
   - copyright
     - profiles_settings.xml
     - .name
     - compiler.xml
     - misc.xml
     - modules.xml
     - vcs.xml
     - workspace.xml
  - src
     - untitled3.iml
- external libraries
```

I can't see where is the design tab go.
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is android studio configuration problem with missing files structure.

First, you have to uninstall this version and you have to follow these steps which are mentioned below:

1. Download upgraded version of android studio from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.
2. Reinstall android studio with upgraded version of android sdk with removal of previous version.
3. Reintall upgraded ADT version.
4. Run executable file C:\Android Studio\bin\studio or C:\Android Studio\bin\studio64.
5. Create new project with use this template.
   [image]

I hope it will help you!!