# Error after updating Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio to 1.2.1.1 and now i am trying to create a new project and it shows an error:

> "Error Loading Default Project "
>   Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.shelf.ShelveChangesManager'

Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain steps to occur error.

Comment: when i clicked on File-New-New Project and mention the name to project, it shows the error

Comment: Have you restarted android studio after updation complete.

Comment: I done it 10 to 15 times !

Answer (score 4):

Experienced the same problem on Ubuntu/Linux. 
In my case the solution was to change the save path of my project from relative, to absolute.

Trying to create a new project in ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp would generate this error

But if I specified the full path /home/myusername/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset Android Studio and this is a configuration problem.

Uninstall android studio and install again.

This link will help you with all steps of reinstall.
[Unable to create new android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205398/unable-to-create-new-android-studio-project/30206143#30206143)

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same error:
'com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.shelf.ShelveChangesManager'

Make sure that you have permissions to write to the project path.
android studio stores the project in the last location you loaded from and in my case it was a Flash Drive...

@Garima Mathur's answer suggests that is a 'configuration problem'
If it's a 'configuration problem' you can delete(*or better rename) the configuration folder.
which is located in the c:\users\CURRENT_USER\.AndroidStudio1.2

but in my case the solution was to change the path of the project to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, I tried to figure it by my self and it worked.

Try this, open your old project, then in your old project window, go to file > new > new project, and it will show the new project window to let you setup your project, after you finish your project setup, click finish and your project will start building and it will bring you to your new project window.
That's all, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error of "Error Loading Default Project"

> Fatal error initializing
>   'com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.shelf.ShelveChangesManager'

and I figured out where the error was coming from. Previous I was running my project from a USB key labeled volume F. Later when I opened `Android studio` after unplugging, the default storage path was still F. Make sure your path is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Following process worked fine for me:

1. Open your any old project in android studio.
2. Go to File > New > New Project.
3. Set Name to your Application.
4. At bottom of window there is  "Project Location TextField".
5. Just change the Location Path to the desired folder and click Next Button.